# Form attr - undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm creating a form programmically via:

```
var form = new Element('form', {
    method: 'post', 
    id: 'formOne', 
    name: 'formOne', 
    action: 'example.example'
});
form.insert(new Element('input', {name: 'csv', value: 'Empty', type: 'hidden'}));
$(document.body).insert(form);
```

`$('formOne')` in the console returns: - yes, without # selector

```
<form method="post" id="formOne" name="formOne" action="example.example"><input name="csv" value="Value" type="hidden"></form>
```

`$('#formOne')` in the console returns null

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Why is that? I am including the following files in the following order:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js-custom/prototype.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

EDIT: apologies, errors in my example code

Comment: `f1` is not a default element, thus you must use a .class or #id reference, and still, neither match your html

Comment: `$('#formOne').attr` - you are missing the # - no need to actually answer this question

Comment: Sorry, I am using formOne everywhere, it was just a mistake in my simplified example

Comment: But you still need the # to define the ID in the selector

Comment: why $('formOne') works then? $('#formOne') gives an error

Comment: I do not believe it works unless you have a tag `<formOne>` somewhere. If `$("#formOne")` gives error you may have more than one object with id="formOne"

Comment: What is Element by the way. perhaps you mean `document.createElement` ? What framework has `Element` as a constructor?

Comment: prototype.js. Also, I do not have any extra formOne objects

Comment: Can you NOT use prototype and instead stay on jQuery? `var $form = $('<form/>', {
    method: 'post', 
    id: 'formOne', 
    name: 'formOne', 
    action: 'example.example'
});
$form.append($('<input/>', {name: 'csv', value: 'Empty', type: 'hidden'}));
$(document.body).append($form);`

Comment: As you're using prototype and jQuery, are you using the `jQuery.noConflict`? If not, only prototype will be able to use the `$`.

Comment: How do you go about changing the values of input fields if form is never printed to the document but rather kept as a variable? (jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `f1` but your form ID is indeed `formOne`.

Change it to

```
$('#formOne').attr('action')
```

to refer to the right form object.

Comment: Sorry, I am using formOne everywhere, it was just a mistake in my simplified example

Comment: @LucasSeveryn Have you forgotten the preceding `#`? Without it, jQuery will look for the element type `formOne` instead of an element with ID `formOne`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `f1` selector will look for `f1` tag and since there is no `f1` tag element it will not return anything.

You have to use the right selector like, by name `[name="formOne"]` or by id `#formOne`

Try this.

```
$('#formOne').attr('action')
```

`$('form')` worked because jQuery could find the element with tag name `form`.

**After editing your question**

I think when you are trying `$('formOne')` in the console `$` is not the jQuery object but some other library may be `prototype.js`. Can you check what `$('formOne').jquery` returns in the console? It it returns `undefined` then you cannot use jQuery method on some other library.

Comment: Sorry, I am using formOne everywhere, it was just a mistake in my simplified example

Comment: also $('myName') works as well if I change the name and id of the form to myName

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mplungjan and @War10ck I learned that I can not use prototype and jQuery at once without `jQuery.noConflict`